# Can't find resource for bundle java.util

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have tow properties files :

config-app.properties

config-dev.properties

and i try to read from the fist witch read also from the second like that :

***the java code:***

```
String smtpHostName = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config-app").getString("smtp.host.name");
```

***config-app.properties***

```
smtp.host.name  =${smtp.host.name.env}
```

***config-dev.properties***

```
smtp.host.name.env  =smtp.gmail.com
```

but i have that message :

```
Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle
```

Edit: Code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, assuming `config-app.properties` exists in the class path (in the root).  You should not get the error "Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle".

However, what you're trying to do, by substituting ${smtp.host.name.env}, will NOT work with ResourceBundle.  You would need another library to do something more complicated like that.

**UPDATED**

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but assuming you want to have profile for developement and another one for production, you could try to do something like this:

```
Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
defaultProperties.load(new FileInputStream("config-app.properties"));

Properties properties = new Properties(defaultProperties);
if (isDev()) {
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("config-dev.properties"));
} else {
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("whatever.properties"));
}

properties.getProperty("smtp.host.name");
```

This will have default settings in `config-app.properties`, which can be overwritten in `config-dev.properties` or `whatever.properties` as needed.  In this case the keep must be the same.

config-app.properties:

```
smtp.host.name =localhost
```

config-dev.properties:

```
smtp.host.name =smtp.gmail.com
```

One last note, the previous code is loading the files from the filesystem, if you have them in the classpath, use something like :

```
defaultProperties.load(Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config-app.properties"));
```

Comment: i foud that i have to remove write like that : smtp.host.name.env =smtpgmailcom but it's not good for my work :(

Comment: i khnow this but why when i remove the point it works (smtp.host.name.env =smtpgmailcom)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.  If you could post a simple complete example, maybe we can see what's going on.

Comment: i made the example in my answer after the yours